# class ThrowingSupplier not found

Tags: java, spring, classnotfoundexception

I'm having this issue when I start my project

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/util/function/ThrowingSupplier
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1012) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:150) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:862) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:760) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:681) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:639) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.RootBeanDefinition.setInstanceSupplier(RootBeanDefinition.java:438) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionBuilder.rootBeanDefinition(BeanDefinitionBuilder.java:129) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionBuilder.rootBeanDefinition(BeanDefinitionBuilder.java:141) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SharedMetadataReaderFactoryContextInitializer$CachingMetadataReaderFactoryPostProcessor.register(SharedMetadataReaderFactoryContextInitializer.java:104) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SharedMetadataReaderFactoryContextInitializer$CachingMetadataReaderFactoryPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(SharedMetadataReaderFactoryContextInitializer.java:97) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:87) ~[spring-context-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:746) ~[spring-context-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:564) ~[spring-context-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147) ~[spring-boot-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:731) ~[spring-boot-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) ~[spring-boot-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) ~[spring-boot-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1303) ~[spring-boot-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1292) ~[spring-boot-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
    at br.com.biblioteca.BibliotecaApiApplication.main(BibliotecaApiApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingSupplier
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520) ~[na:na]
    ... 24 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 1
```

I honestly have no idea what's going on. I searched on google and didn't find any answer that would help me, I even put it in chatgpt and also nothing.

my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.7</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>br.com.biblioteca</groupId>
    <artifactId>biblioteca-api</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>biblioteca-api</name>
    <description>API da biblioteca da gertrudes</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.5.1</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

if necessary I can commit my code and make it available here for you guys, to try to run.

I googled and didn't find anything relevant.

Comment: Mixing jars from different versions. Remove the `spring-beans` dependency.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is your dependencies which break things.

**TL;DR:** Remove the `spring-beans` dependency as that is incompatible with your setup.

### Explanation:

You are using Spring Boot 2.7.7 which uses Spring 5.3.x. You have however includes `spring-beans` for version `6.0.3` which is incompatible with Spring Boot 2.7.7 (it is required/used by Spring Boot 3.0.x).

Remove that dependency as that will already be pulled in by the other dependencies. Which makes me wonder why you decided to include this in the first place?

Comment: I'm also wondering why I put this there. But I took it and it worked, thank you very much